# Managing dependencies between database tables when inserting data with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

Is it possible to insert data into a SQL Database using SQL Alchemy without using `flush()` to manage a dependency between two tables which are linked with a foreign key?

I have two tables with a foreign key relationship.

- The first table contains data about some object, which has a fixed location in space. It is a "thing" which exists somewhere. You could imagine it to have a latitude and longitude, if you want.
- The second table describes where the "thing" is. The location of the "thing" is not stored in the first table itself. Instead, the second table is used to "tag" where items in the first table are located.

For example, if a "thing" has a particular latitude and longitude, it may also have other ways to describe its location.

- It may exist in a country, for example

When creating the tables with SQL Alchemy, I perform the following operations.

1. **Create an object to represent a new row, which may or may not exist in the database**

```
class FirstTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'first'

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    data: Mapped[str]

def create_first_table_row(data: str) -> FirstTableRow:
    row = FirstTable(data=data)
    return row

def get_or_insert_first_table_row(session, row):
    existing_row = session.execute(select(FirstTable).where(FirstTable.data == row.data)).scalar()
    if existing_row is None:
        session.add(row)
        return row
    else:
        return existing_row
```

The code used to do this is as follows

```
first_row = create_first_table_row(data)
first_row = get_or_insert_first_table_row(session, first_row)
session.flush()
```

The `session.flush()` appears to be requried between the insertion of this row and the row which follows. I assume this is what is causing my insertion logic to run slowly, because `flush()` is continually hammering the database and causing a sync point.

2. **Create an object to represent the second table row, which may or may not exist in the database**

Similar to the above:

```
second_row = create_second_table_row(first_row)
second_row = get_or_insert_second_table_row(session, second_row)
# session.flush() is not required
```

Rows are inserted in batches. So about 100 rows are inserted, and then a `session.commit()` is dispatched, forcing a sync.

If I remove the `flush()` between creating the first row and the second, I start to see errors because the first row does not have a primary key. (It is `None`.) Therefore the second row cannot be inserted. It fails because it has a column which references the primary key of the first row, which cannot be null.

Comment: Usually you would define a relationship between the two tables, and add the related object(s) when creating the parent object, something like `parent = Parent(name='Alice', related_objs=[...])`. That way SQLA will handle the id bookkeeping automatically.

Comment: The issue there I think is if the `Parent` object already exists in the database. I can't add it again (it will be a duplicate, and there is a unique constraint which prevents this) so what to do? I need to query the database for existing rows first, only then can I add child objects, because those child objects cannot exist without the key from the parent.

Comment: Not sure if that is clear or makes sense?

Comment: There is a section in the [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/orm_related_objects.html#tutorial-orm-related-objects) that may help explain how SQLAlchemy handles relationships.